# phpMyAdmin (v5.2): How to display binary as hex?

Tags: phpmyadmin, binary, hex

phpMyAdmin is displaying a binary byte as a character when it is printable, but as hexadecimal when it is not (e.g., 0x4B). I want it to only display hexadecimal (because I want to see the bit pattern).

I did a search and found the suggestion to use:
`$cfg['DisplayBinaryAsHex'] = TRUE;`
in the config.inc.php file, but it does not work. I searched the v5.2 documentation and there is no reference to `DisplayBinaryAsHex`. The documentation does reference
`$cfg['DefaultTransformations']['Hex']`
but I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation about what it does or how to use it.

Is there any way to force phpMyAdmin to display binary as hex?